# PHP Unset array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and have keys in separate array. I need to unset the array.

```
 Array
(
[0] => RequestDocument
[1] => Orders
[2] => Order
[3] => OrderProducts
[4] => OrderProduct
)
```

How to loop array to make unset like below.

```
unset(["RequestDocument"]["Orders"]["Order"]["OrderProducts"]["OrderProduct"]);
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Sarnitha

Comment: You want to unset all the elements of your array whose values can be found in another array?

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter) function in this case:

```php
  <?php
   $x = [
       0 => "RequestDocument",
       1 => "Orders",
       2 => "Order",
       3 => "OrderProducts",
       4 => "OrderProduct",
   ];
   
   $filter = [
       "RequestDocument",
       "Orders",
       // "Order",
       "OrderProducts",
       "OrderProduct",
   ];
   
   $y = array_filter($x, function ($el) use ($filter) {
       return !in_array($el, $filter);
   });
```

Test here [PHP online code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=c4bd394bf906273d8f5f8cffeff852fb&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: `array_diff` would be a more straightforward approach.